# One circle maps under another circle - Dynamical Systems

Tags: dynamical-systems

I've researched a lot trying to do this question. The only way I can think of solving this problem is using a differential equation. But it seems this question requires a discrete map to solve it.  Can anyone help?

"Consider the set of points on a circle of radius r about the origin and show that they are mapped under one step of the dynamical system to another circle which you should specify."

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what the dynamical system is

Comment: Hi, dbx, thank you for your time.    " f(x,y)= x^2-y^2+ a;  g(x,y)=2xy+b.  where a, b are constants and b=0" are the conditions I was given.

Answer (score 0):

Your map is $z^2+(a,b)$ and so the circle of radius $r$ centered at $0$ is taken to the circle of radius $r^2$ centered at $(a,b)$. Alternatively you can write
$$
(f(x,y)-a)^2+(g(x,y)-b)^2=(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2=r^4
$$
to conclude the same.

Comment: Thank you, John B.